# output error when I input a space between my strings

Tags: c, string

I wanted to write code to check whether a string is the same when reading it forward or backward(like a palindrome). Here is the code I'm using.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 
    
int main(){
    
    int n, right, left;
    char s[101];
    
    scanf("%100d", &n); 
    getchar();
    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%[^\n]", s); 
        getchar();
        left=0; 
        right=strlen(s); 
            
        while((left<=right)&&(s[left]==s[right-1])){ 
            left++; 
            right--;
        }
        
        if(left>right){ 
            printf("True\n"); 
        }else{
            printf("False\n"); 
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

It worked fine if I input a normal string. e.g.

input:

```
aka
bob
abc
```

output:

```
True
True
False
```

If the string is a palindrome then the output is true, otherwise the output is false. This works perfectly fine, but when I input a string with a space in between, the output is not right. e.g.

input:

```
Taco cat
was it a car or a cat I saw
```

output:

```
False
False
```

Both the strings are palindromes and the output should've been true, but it's not. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two failure cases differ in case.  If you want to be case insensitive try:

```
#include <ctype.h>
...
while((left<=right)&&(tolower(s[left])==tolower(s[right-1]))){
```

If you also want to ignore space then you have to advance either left or right on space.  I simplified your program to only look at one string:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN 101

int main() {
    char s[LEN];
    fgets(s, LEN, stdin);
    for(int left = 0, right = strlen(s) - 1; left < right; ) {
        if(isspace(s[left])) {
            left++;
            continue;
        }
        if(isspace(s[right])) {
            right--;
            continue;
        }
        if(tolower(s[left]) != tolower(s[right])) {
            printf("False\n");
            return 0;
        }
        left++;
        right--;
    }
    printf("True\n");
    return 0;
}
```